# passing cascade dropdown value to Gallery on next screen, PowerApps

Tags: parameter-passing, powerapps, cascadingdropdown

I'm doing POC on PowerApps and need help and advice

I connect my app to Excel as data source, ~ 800 records. I intend to pass these cascade dropdown value to my next screen in order to filter my Gallery displaying bunch of data.  But I got no value in my Gallery.

Then i continue my experiment to test passing value with Label.  I formulate my Next button in passing ONE dropdown value to next screen -- *Navigate(Scr_Result,ScreenTransition.Cover,{selectedSite: drop_assetsite.Selected.Result* --, i successfully get that value. But when I combine those 3 dropdown value on my NAVIGATE function, i got FALSE on my label text instead

Here is my NEXT navigate formula --- *Navigate(Scr_Result,ScreenTransition.Cover,{selectedSite: drop_assetsite.Selected.Result And drop_building.Selected.Result And drop_assetcategory.Selected.Result})*  But i found no red X mark on my NEXT button.

[image: my main screen]

I'm not quite sure that I can combine those cascade value in one argument on Navigate or not.  I can't find this combination somewhere.  Thanks in advance for all replied.  ^_^ and sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression like this one:

```
Navigate(
    Scr_Result,
    ScreenTransition.Cover,
    {
        selectedSite: drop_assetsite.Selected.Result,
        selectedBuilding: drop_building.Selected.Result,
        selectedCategory: drop_assetcategory.Selected.Result
    })
```

And in `Scr_Result` you can access the three values (selectedSite, selectedBuilding, selectedCategory) in any expressions on that screen.

Comment: Hi Carlosfigueira, thanks for your advice.  i got my expected result.